# Gradle copy command deprecated, breaks build

Tags: java, gradle

In Gradle 3.x I was able to get some xml mapping files to copy into the classes directory prior to build/jar via the following block:

```
copy{

  from 'src/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  into 'build/classes/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  include '**/*.xml'

}
```

In Gradle 4.9 this has been deprecated in favor of:

```
task copyMappings(type: Copy){

  from 'src/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  into 'build/classes/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  include '**/*.xml'

}
```

The copyMappings task succeeds, but build/jar does not wait for copyMappings to finish.  I have tried variations on build.dependsOn and doFirst{ copyMappings } doLast{ build } but nothing seems to get me the desired effect of having the copied files in place in the 'into' path prior to jar.
This is for Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you say `build.dependsOn()` is deprecated? That doesn't sound correct.

Comment: It might be useful (for others) to state which OS you were using?

Comment: This is for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to model things around source sets where appropriate as doing so let's the build work more reliably with a wide range of plugins and use cases. For example, imagine you want to run an application direct from its class files and resources rather than packaging it as a JAR first. You could make sure that the "run" task depends on the copy as well, but you'd have to do that for every instance where this is a requirement.

Source sets are the ideal solution because they have the concept of a runtime classpath, which will work for packaging, instrumentation, running, testing and so on.

With that in mind, I would go for this simple declaration and get rid of the copy task:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/java"
            include "**/*.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

The XML files will end up in a different directory from your current approach, but that shouldn't matter unless you have tasks that assume the location rather than using the source set model to get the necessary information.

**Note** The above `include` directive applies to all the resources in *src/main/resources* as well. So if you have properties files or text files or anything else in there, they will be excluded. The simplest solution is to add all required resource file patterns to the `include` directive.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Gradle 4.9 on Mac OS:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task copyMappings(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  into 'build/classes/main/java/com/company/mapping'
  include '**/*.xml'
}

jar.dependsOn copyMappings

jar.doFirst {
    assert new File("${projectDir}/build/classes/main/java/com/company/mapping/abc.xml").exists()
    assert new File("${projectDir}/build/classes/main/java/com/company/mapping/def.xml").exists()
}
```

command line is `gradle clean jar`

Comment: This does not work for me in Gradle 4.9.  It returns the same result as my original approach.  The files make it into the build/classes directory but build / jar occur before the file copy has succeeded.